# Android App is crashing on launch in the emulator

Tags: android, firebase

My App is working fine in the actual device where as it's crashing on launch in the emulator. below is the log.

```txt
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: EMAILADDRESS=certadmin@netskope.com, CN=caadmin.netskope.com, O=netSkope Inc, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.setDefaultAttributesToBundle(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:55)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.startRpc(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:37)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.GmsRpc.getToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:13)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$2$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:164)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$4.start(Unknown Source:8)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.RequestDeduplicator.getOrStartGetTokenRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:14)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.lambda$getInstanceId$3$FirebaseInstanceId(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.3:163)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId$$Lambda$1.then(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: EMAILADDRESS=certadmin@netskope.com, CN=caadmin.netskope.com, O=netSkope Inc, L=London, ST=London, C=GB
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every app has to explicitly add the user defined certificates:

res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
            <certificates src="user"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Also make sure the AndroidManifest.xml contains the android:networkSecurityConfig attribute in the  tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```